# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '../commands' discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to read all of the files that are in a directory, but I got an error.
My code:

```js
        const Commands = []
        readdirSync("../commands").forEach((folder) => {
            readdirSync(`../commands/${folder}`).forEach((file) => {
                const command = require(`../commands/${folder}/${file}`);
                if (!command.name) return;
                Commands.push(command);
            })
        })
```

The error:

```
<rejected> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '../commands'
```

I am using discord.js v13 and node.js v16

**Notes**: main.js is not in the commands folder.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.
I just needed to replace that code with this one:

```js
const Commands = []
        readdirSync("./commands").forEach((file) => {
                const command = require(`../commands/${file}`);
                if (!command.name) return;
                Commands.push(command);

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

In node, the relative paths for fs functions are from the path of the entrypoint file (your index.js), so in this case, instead of putting `../commands` (which would be correct if you started your command with commands.js, but you have not), you need to put `./commands` (I am assuming the commands folder is in the same folder as your index.js)

Comment: index.js is in another folder.

Comment: but when I replaced my code with yours, I got another error:`Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, scandir './commands/8ball.js'
`

Comment: Well, that is another issue with your code, your code is not checking if the file it is trying to read is a folder or not,  you are assuming everything in your commands folder to be a folder, which obviously isnt true. You should do a check if the file read is a folder or not, and then only recurse into it. What I told you did work if it got that far.